# How would I make an encrypt code in Python?

Tags: python

How would I make an encrypt code in python? For example, if I have this:

word = input("Enter a word: ")

How would I make it so that every "A" turns into a "B", or every "X" turns into a "Y"? Every letter turns into the letter after it.

Comment: For this, have you researched anything?

Comment: Have a try yourself - there are many ways to do it. The only way to learn to program is by practicing. This is called a Caesar Cipher by the way, but I'd encourage you to try it on your own before searching. Incidentally, I assume that you realize that this is completely worthless as an actual security measure, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ord` and `chr` functions. Changing a letter to the next would be something like

```
next_letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)
```

Comment: you'd also want to have logic or modulo for z, and case matters

Comment: @depperm: good points, both. but the question is not specific enough, so I just mentioned the two basic functions.